# How to get the percentage of Woocommerce regular and sale price in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am just trying to display Message `You save $percentage` after regular and sale price on single product page but unable to do it as it gives error if i try to get the difference percentage using the following code.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3);
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price($price, $regular_price, $sale_price)
{
    $percentage = round(($regular_price - $sale_price) / $regular_price * 100) . '%';
    $percentage_txt = ' ' . __('You Save ', 'woocommerce') . $percentage;
    $price = '<del>' . (is_numeric($regular_price) ? wc_price($regular_price) : $regular_price) . '</del> <ins>' . (is_numeric($sale_price) ? wc_price($sale_price) . $percentage_txt : $sale_price . $percentage_txt) . '</ins>';
    return $price;
}
```

Any one can help what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you share the error?

Comment: it is just displaying the "There has been a critical error on this website."

Comment: You can turn on the debug (in wp-config.php)  and check the error. The error might be at a different function or file.

Comment: Deprecated: strstr(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\my-website\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-page-functions.php on line 139

Comment: This error is being caused by a different function. You're not using strstr in this one. See wc-page-functions.php on line 139

Comment: I tested the code, it's fine. Look for fatal or critical error logs and find out what actually causing the error.